# include statement not working in Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[The official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices?hl=en#separate_html_css_and_javascript) for HTML best practices says that files can be included with `<?!= include(myFile); ?>`. However, when I go to try it myself, it prints literally on my page. [image]WHY!?

My actual HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css>
    <?!= include('stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="center">Pothole sheet generator</h1>
    <!-- Create central box -->
    <!--<div style="position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px;"> -->
    <div class="pageCenter">
      <form style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        <h2 class="center">Initial measurements</h2>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

stylesheet.html

```
<style>


.center
{
    text-align: center;
}


.pageCenter
 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

UPDATE: I learned that the `include()` is server-side function.
However, when I added it in my `code.gs` file, I still have the same problem!

code.gs

```
function myFunction() {
  doGet(); // display html
}

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('prompt');
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

Comment: Somehow, Google script tag does not exist.

Comment: This is not regular html, it's meant to be used with Google's HTML service

Comment: @Axnff I know. It's my intention; /* in regular HTML, I would have simply called the stylesheet `myPage.css` and used a `<link>` tag to reference it. */

Comment: I took out the "dead" code for clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `createTemplateFromFile` in the doGet method.

```
function doGet(){
return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('prompt') 
          .evaluate()
          .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);  
}
```

Comment: I did in my original code, but accidentally deleted it here. I fixed it here.

Comment: Here's a copy of the project: https://script.google.com/d/1p6GTbxuXNdA2mAg087fTw2RhV-ubpNk7uQs6lGJb2XKT57Yu1yBy3O2x/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have modified the code...there is error in your doGet method